# how to suppress warning when starting Links from favorites

Tags: windows-7, links, security-warning

I have several batch files and other programs that I use regularly linked from my Favorites folder and I display that folder in my task bar.

Now every time I start each of that programs I am prompted with a security warning that programs from the Internet are dangerous.

I don't have a check box or anything in that warning that I could check to indicate that this file is fine and no thread at all. (In fact I wrote them myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be resolved by telling windows that the files in the folder are to be trusted.

You have to open a command line prompt and issue the command:

```
ICACLS "CORRECT_PATH" /Setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)M
```

Where `CORRECT_PATH` is `C:\Users\USER_NAME\Favorites\Verknüpfungen` on my computer (a German version) so its most likely `C:\Users\USER_NAME\Favorites\Links` for English ones. Replace "USER_NAME" by your user name. You can find this easily by opening a command line with the `cmd` command (type it in the search bar of your start menu) and using:

```
cd Favorites
dir
```

`ICACLS` is the windows program to manipulate the security settings of files and folders. The option `/setintegritylevel` manipulates the trust levels. The options mean `(OI)` Objects inherit the settings, `(CI)` Containers inherit the settings, `M` Medium trust.

You can issue `ICACLS /?` to get more information.